# Is the estimate $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} f(x)dx = o\left(\frac{1}{k^{1-\alpha}}\right)$ true?

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, oscillatory-integral

Let $0<\alpha<1$. First, we have an estimate
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} dx = O\left(\frac{1}{k^{1-\alpha}}\right), \quad k\to\infty,$$
obtained by substituting $kx=x'$. It is notable that the power-law singularity at $x=0$ gives the fractional leading order term. This is in contrast with the standard stationary phase lemma, which gives $O(1/k^n)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. (I would also appreciate if someone gives any references that deals with fractional leading term due to singularity.)

Motivated from this, consider the following situation. Let $f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function that satisfies
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 0.$$
Hence, we can continuously extend $f$ to the domain $[0,\infty)$. Furthermore, assume that $f$ has compact support. One example of such $f$ is $f(x) = x^\beta \chi(x)$, where $\beta>0$ and $\chi(x)$ is a bump function supported near 0.

**My question**: do we have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} f(x)dx = o\left(\frac{1}{k^{1-\alpha}}\right) ?$$

If $f$ can be written as $f(x)=xg(x)$ using a non-singular function $g$ with well-defined $g(0)$, then the problem is trivial by integrating by parts. However, if we cannot assume this, I cannot figure out the answer.

Comment: $\mathcal{M}_x\left[e^{i k x}\right](1-\alpha )=\int\limits_0^{\infty } e^{i k x} x^{-\alpha }\ dx=(-i k)^{\alpha -1}\ \Gamma(1-\alpha )\,, \Re(\alpha)<1\land \Im(k)>0$ (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MellinTransform%5BE%5E%28I+k+x%29%2C+x%2C+1+-+%5C%5BAlpha%5D%5D). Mathematica gave the conditions.

Comment: @StevenClark My question is not about that....

Comment: What does $k\to\infty$ mean when the Mellin Transform integral only converges for $\Im(k)>0$? Do you mean $\Re(k)\to\infty$?

Comment: @StevenClark Oh, I forgot to mention that $k$ is real.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your starting point now. With the substitution $y=k x$ the integral $\int\limits_0^\infty e^{i k x}\ x^{-\alpha}\ dx$ becomes $k^{\alpha -1} \int\limits_0^{\infty } e^{i y} y^{-\alpha } \, dy=i e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha } \Gamma (1-\alpha ) k^{\alpha -1}$ for $0<\Re(\alpha)<1$. And $\underset{k\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(i e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha } \Gamma (1-\alpha ) k^{\alpha -1}\right)=0$ for $0<\Re(\alpha )<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a counterexample:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} e^{\frac ix - x} dx =O\left(\frac{1}{k^{3/4-\alpha/2}}\right),$$
since this is not necessarily of $O(1/k^{1-\alpha})$.
The proof of this counterexample is in [Proving the asymptotic expansion $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} e^{\frac ix - x} dx =O\left(\frac{1}{k^{3/4-\alpha/2}}\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284055/proving-the-asymptotic-expansion-int-0-infty-fraceikxx-alpha-e-fra).