# Proving the asymptotic expansion $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} e^{\frac ix - x} dx =O\left(\frac{1}{k^{3/4-\alpha/2}}\right) $

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

For $0<\alpha<1$, what is the asymptotic expression of the (absolute value of the) integral
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} e^{\frac ix - x} dx, \quad k\to\infty?$$

Mathematica can exactly evaluate the integral as a complicated function as follows:

```
-(-1)^(1/4) (-I)^a E^(1/4 I (-1 + a) \[Pi]) (I + k)^(
 1/2 (-1 + a)) \[Pi] Csc[
  a \[Pi]] (Cos[(a \[Pi])/4] + 
   I Sin[(a \[Pi])/4]) (I Cos[(a \[Pi])/2] KelvinBer[
     1 - a, -2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I + k]] + 
   I Cos[(a \[Pi])/2] KelvinBer[-1 + a, -2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I + k]] + 
   KelvinBei[
     1 - a, -2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I + k]] (Cos[(a \[Pi])/2] - 
      I Sin[(a \[Pi])/2]) + 
   KelvinBei[-1 + a, -2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I + k]] (Cos[(a \[Pi])/2] + 
      I Sin[(a \[Pi])/2]) + 
   KelvinBer[1 - a, -2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I + k]] Sin[(a \[Pi])/2] - 
   KelvinBer[-1 + a, -2 (-1)^(3/4) Sqrt[I + k]] Sin[(a \[Pi])/2])
```

I also performed the numerical integration for both $\alpha=0.2$ and $\alpha=0.4$. The result is,
$$I= O\left(\frac{1}{k^{0.645}}\right) \textrm{ for } \alpha=0.2, \quad I=O\left(\frac{1}{k^{0.544}}\right) \textrm{ for } \alpha=0.4.$$
Maybe I suspect
$$I= O\left(\frac{1}{k^{3/4-\alpha/2}}\right)$$
for general $\alpha$?? (Edit: I found out this is indeed true by manual asymptotic expression of the analytical result. Then, **how can I prove this result in a more clever way?**)

Note that for a general smooth bounded function $f$, we have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{x^\alpha} f(x) e^{-x}dx = O\left(\frac{1}{k^{1-\alpha}}\right).$$
However, my numerical result indicates that the integral decays slower if we have a very rapid oscillation like $e^{\frac ix}$! This is why I am interested in this question.

Comment: What are you looking : the real part or the imaginary one ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The absolute value!

Comment: Rewrite your fancy `KelvinBei` in terms of Bessel functions, and use [well-known asymptotic expansions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.17).

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks. By explicitly performing asymptotic expansion manually, I found out that $O(1/k^{3/4-\alpha/2})$ behavior is correct. However, is there more clever way to do this?

Comment: With the substitution $x = tk^{ - 1/2}$, we obtain $$
I=\frac{1}{{k^{1/2 - \alpha /2} }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( {i\sqrt k \left( {t + \frac{1}{t}} \right)} \right)\frac{{\exp \left( { - tk^{ - 1/2} } \right)}}{{t^\alpha  }}dt} .
$$ Now the sole stationary point is at $t=1$, and the integral is of order $k^{-1/4}$ by the method of stationary phase. For the more general case, you can again apply the stationary phase method, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.iv

Comment: @Gary Thanks so much! I think your comment sufficiently answers my question.